# Which [LINQ]?​​​​​​

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-disambiguation

I feel like [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) is a pretty bad tag to have around and should be deprecated (remain on older posts only) with linq to xxx being the only alternative. A lot of questions on LINQ, especially begginer level ones, just have the LINQ tag and not enough context to infer the LINQ being used (typically one of to SQL , to entities or to objects), yet most of the time the correct answer varies a lot depending on which one is being used.

I'm confident that removing this tag and forcing users to chose another more specific one would improve the response time for these questions (which often end up with comments about which linq this is, and edits to the question, and wrong answers in the meantime).

Comment: People new to Linq probably won't even know that it has different flavors or what those flavors do, or what the subtleties are between them, which is going to result in a lot of improperly tagged questions and bad/wrong answers. Vague tags are better than wrong tags.

Comment: The tags are pretty clear on what is what. It wouldn't be perfect but it would be an improvement

Comment: Good luck getting a new user to actually read tag descriptions.

Comment: But what about more generic linq solutions that work for several or all of the different flavors?  Do you want to make people used all 4 LINQ-to-X tags?

Comment: The main problem with the tag [tag:linq] is when [users erroneously edit out linq-to-sql and replace it with linq](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2682264/revisions). If this relates to you: **STOP**.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not. I don't follow any of those tags, so I don't know if there's really a big problem with people commenting and editing posts to be more specific.

I do know that there are way more people following the [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) tag than any of the others you mentioned. The questions in that tag also appear to be getting answered at approximately the same rate as the others.

- [`linq` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq/topusers)
- [`linq-to-sql` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-sql/topusers)
- [`linq-to-xml` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-xml/topusers)
- [`linq-to-entities` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-entities/topusers)
- [`linq-to-objects` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-objects/topusers)

I think that deprecating the tag might cause confusion in new users, and worse, might fracture the community of users who are now spending time answering questions from the generic [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq) tag.